# Unable to extract the data from previous response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where the request saves the data using PUT method. The dynamic content is webkit(json body). So kindly help me how to capture the value.

Thanks
Roshan

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract value(s) from the previous response the options are in:

1. [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) - if you provide a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name and empty left and right boundaries - it will store the whole response into that variable
2. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) - allows extraction of partial data using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query language
3. [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) - the same as point 2 but uses a different language - [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) which is is more "standard" and powerful
4. More complex extractions/transformations can be done using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) language

We cannot "kindly help you" more without seeing the previous response and the next request, the only "help" I can provide so far is a piece of information that WebKit is a [browser engine](https://webkit.org/) so I have a doubt regarding your statement about sending it somewhere.